# Rewriting an SQL Query Without Using Intersect Operator

Tags: mysql, sql, querying

I want to query this statement:

```
Bars that are frequented by both Mike and John
```

[table frequents consists of 2 columns: drinkers and the bars they go to]

I originally thought of using this SQL query, using the intersect operator:

```
SELECT  bar
FROM frequents
WHERE drinker ='Mike'
INTERSECT
SELECT bar
FROM frequents
WHERE drinker ='John'
```

but MySQL doesn't support the usage of the Intersect operator. I though of maybe using the Join operator, but I am have a difficult time rewriting this query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an `inner join` you want:

```
SELECT a.bar
FROM frequents a
JOIN frequents b ON a.bar = b.bar 
WHERE a.drinker = 'Mike'
  AND b.drinker = 'John';
```

Note that the intersect compares all columns in the select list, so the equivalent join needs to do the same. In your case it's just one column though.

The `intersect` operator doesn't really translate directly to an `inner join` though as `intersect` returns rows that are common to the sets compared, while the join filters on given conditions and produces a new set of rows that are made up from the rows in the joined sets. There are also differences in how `null` values are handled (and duplicates).

Another option would be to use the `exists` predicate with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT a.bar
FROM frequents a
WHERE a.drinker ='Mike'
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM frequents b 
    WHERE a.bar = b.bar
      AND b.drinker ='John'
    );
```

Or the `in` predicate:

```
SELECT bar
FROM frequents
WHERE drinker ='Mike'
AND bar IN (SELECT bar FROM frequents WHERE drinker ='John')
```

There are many other ways to do this, but I think I'll stop here :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is using aggregation:

```
select f.bar
from frequents f
group by f.bar
having max(drinker = 'John') > 0 and
       max(drinker = 'Mike) > 0;
```

Or:

```
select f.bar
from frequents f
where f.drinker in ('John', 'Mike')
group by f.bar
having count(*) = 2;
```

I like the `having` clause because I find it flexible for a wide range of conditions, such as John and Mike, but not Sara.  Or three of John, Mike, Sara, and Abigail.